# Is "in two-yearly intervals" a proper construction?

Tags: adjectives, numbers, attributive-nouns, premodifiers, attributive-adjectives

There's this construction, "x-yearly intervals", in a textbook I found.

> The graph shows Europe's jay population from 1996-2004 at two-yearly intervals.

Shouldn't it be "two-**year** intervals" instead?

Comment: I'd read two-yearly to mean two a year, but the graph showed '96, '98, to '04? Show us the graph, please. If every two years, then two-year is right. But 4 intervals or 16?

Comment: @YosefBaskin lol, just came up with that off the top of my head, forgot how math works. Also, can't show you a graph, this is a made-up, paraphrased example. I'm not really allowed to disclose the original material. Point is the x-axis only includes such years as 96, 98, ... , 2002, 2004.

Comment: "two-year intervals" seems correct. The author was overgeneralizing from "biyearly", which would be correct for 6-month intervals.

Comment: How is this not simply a matter of personal choice about style?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Because it might be a matter of grammatical correctness? In what way is this "simple" to you?

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw Sorry… my 'simply' did not mean 'easily'. It meant 'only' or 'solely' or 'nothing other than…' I happen to prefer either 'two-year intervals' or 'two-yearly' with no mention of intervals… and I'm quite sure most native speakers of English would not notice there was a difference.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Then you are free to prove your "quite sure" conjecture with a well-sourced answer. Otherwise your comment, framed as a question by the way, has no applicable value. I didn't ask this question because I thought it was just a matter of style or preference. I asked because I thought there might be something grammatically wrong with it.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Also, "with no mention of intervals" isn't remotely the point. I mentioned the word "intervals" for a reason. It's not there for show. The point is whether such construction as "two-yearly" would be grammatically correct placed in front of such noun as "intervals".

Comment: As per research done by @eltomito and Sven Yargs, both "x-year"  and "x-yearly" are correct. And there are regional differences in their use. Answers to this question also  cleared for me the use of adjective and *multiple word noun-adjuncts* to modify another noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I've never come across that usage, and almost clocked it as ungrammatical, the HANSARD corpus (British Parliament) produces plenty of results across the years, with the meaning of 'every two years'.

> 1971 - each pensioner will get a cost of living increase measured over a two-year period and he will get it at **two-yearl**y intervals
>
> 1975 - The second matter of substance concerns the review period--;
> whether it should be annually, **two-yearly** or three-yearly: The
> more I have considered, the more I have been persuaded that it is in
> the interests of all concerned that the review should be annually:
> Although there is a fear on the part of tenants that there will be
> more frequent increases, against that there is the valid point that a
> site owner who has to decide in the next couple of months what he
> considers the right rent to fix for two years ahead might, in the
> present inflationary situation, wish to cover himself for a
> substantial amount in view of possible increases in electricity and
> water charges, rates, labour costs and other possible eventualities:
>
> 1984 - If a trade union wants a system of ballots at branches or
> workplaces, or a system of annual, **two-yearly** or three-yearly
> elections, why should it not be free to have them?
>
> 2001 - That is important, especially in relation to London: As she
> knows, the **two-yearly** scheme in London must be renegotiated at the
> beginning of 2002, and that poses a particular problem for the
> capital: If the Bill comes into operation before the end of this year,
> London will be able to incorporate it into the new scheme that starts
> in 2002; otherwise, it will have two options: Either it must pay for
> the additional scheme for a year, or the operation of the scheme will
> be delayed until 2004
>
> 2004 - Subsequent analyses will be undertaken at **two-yearly**
> intervals

The above is a sample of the 170 total hits. Note that some could not be replaced with *two-year* without making us question whether they were referring to frequency or duration. For reference, *two-yearly intervals* returned 46 hits, *two-year intervals* 22 hits, *two year intervals* 1 hit, *intervals of two years* 13 hits.

In any case, among this group of prestige-dialect speakers, the usage is common enough, which would indicate that the sentence in question is acceptable to at least some English speakers.

However, *two-yearly* yielded no results in the Corpus of US Supreme Court Opinions, the Corpus of Historical American English, or the Time Magazine Corpus.

Answer (score 4):

I did a quick survey of of Google Books search results for "two-yearly intervals" and "two-year intervals." Google Books returned approximately 250 verifiable matches for "two-yearly intervals" (some lacking hyphens) and approximately 180 verifiable matches for "two-year intervals" (again, some lacking hyphens).

With the search results in hand, I checked the place of publication and author's workplace (if identified) for the first fifty matches in each set of returned titles. I counted all nonduplicate matches that used the hyphenated form "two-yearly intervals" or "two-year intervals" until I reached 50 total matches for each set; I excluded non-hyphenated forms ("two yearly intervals" or "two year intervals") to avoid including examples in either data set that might have been intended to convey a different meaning from "intervals with a duration of two years." The results of this survey were as follows:

***Places of authorship/publication for the first fifty matches for "two-yearly intervals":***

> France 1
>
> Greece 1
>
> Grenada 1
>
> Hong Kong 1
>
> India 2
>
> Netherlands 4
>
> New Zealand 2
>
> Switzerland 1
>
> United Kingdom 33 (one an author based in Australia, one an author based in Ireland)
>
> United States 4 (one from World Bank and one from UN Centre for Disarmament Affairs)

***Places of authorship/publication for the first fifty matches for "two-year intervals":***

> Burma 1
>
> Germany 1
>
> Singapore 1
>
> United Kingdom 4 (one an author based in the US)
>
> United States 42
>
> uncertain (IMF publication with Italian authors but US spelling conventions)

The split between predominant UK usage (of "two-yearly intervals") and predominant U.S. usage (of "two-year intervals") could hardly be more dramatic. The obvious practical conclusion to be drawn from these results is that if you want to sound like a British writer/speaker, you should probably use "two-yearly intervals"; and if you want to sound like a U.S. writer/speaker, you should probably use "two-year intervals."

Comment: Damn, a+ for effort! I had never thought of possible regional preference.

Comment: Second that. A+  for effort

Answer (score 3):

Both "two-year intervals" and "two-yearly intervals" are apparently correct.

1. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yearly) and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/yearly) dictionaries say that "yearly" can be both an adverb and an adjective. Therefore "yearly interval" is correct, because "yearly" acts as an adjective. In the expression "two-yearly interval", you just add an extra modifier to the "yearly" adjective.
2. A "two-year interval" is also correct, because "two-year" can be used as a noun adjunct consisting of several words as described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct#English) which says: "Noun adjuncts can also be strung together in a longer sequence preceding the final noun, with each added noun modifying the noun which follows it, in effect creating a multiple-word noun adjunct which modifies the following noun (e.g. "chicken soup bowl", in which "chicken" modifies "soup" and "chicken soup" modifies "bowl")".

Comment: Thank you for clarifying why both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Generally "in" is not used with "intervals", especially when the time period is mentioned ([example sentences](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/interval)). So the correctly constructed sentence would be any of the three

> The graph shows Europe's jay population from 1996-2004 at two-year intervals.

> The graph shows Europe's jay population from 1996-2004 at intervals of two years.

> The graph shows Europe's jay population from 1996-2004 at 24-month intervals.

I suppose the hyphenated two-year (in the first sentence) (*and not two-years*) is used for ease of use and speed (prosody) and sounds natural to the ears.

This sentence also sounds right  with the  edition of the  word "every".

> The graph shows Europe's jay population from 1996-2004 at intervals of every two years.

### Edit: Why it is better to use "two-year" instead of "two-yearly", though both can be used.

“Two-yearly intervals” is synonymous with “two-year intervals” as per [Power Thesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/two-year_intervals+two-yearly_intervals). I could not find more authoritative source and suppose both can be used in writing. But when it is being said, the listener may erroneously deduce “*two-yearly intervals*” as “*two*” “*yearly intervals*”, which may mean “*every two years*” or “*twice a year*” or only “*twice*” and that too at "*yearly intervals*". Though both can be used it is better to use “two-year intervals” to avoid confusion.

Comment: that "in" was a mistake. rectified.

Comment: “every two years” is better than either.

Answer (score -2):

I’d write either “two-yearly intervals” or “two year intervals”, though the latter is ambiguous (an interval of two years, or two intervals of a year).

Comment: Your first alternative is exactly what's in the question.

Comment: OK. Let’s put it this way: I’m a native speaker so I’m giving an authoritative opinion on two alternatives, one of which is in the question. For me, “two-year intervals” is incorrect: I don’t think that - formally - we use hyphens in that situation in English, which is why I wrote it without a hyphen. However, the second alternative is ambiguous. You might like to argue about whether we should use a hyphen to disambiguate in this situation. Also, I note that you live in the USA: it may be that you and I follow different conventions.

Comment: "two year intervals" sounds like there are two intervals of one year each.